# How to update a certain content of the page when the button is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC to build a simple application. I would like to update a certain div when the button is clicked, I have used Ajax for this, however, Ajax still call a function that would direct to different view. I am not looking to use redirect method because my page take time to load anyway and I would rather just update certain div while staying at the same page.

I have tried the following so far:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchResult";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model IPagedList<JobsOfferSystem.Models.AllJobModel>

@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css">
<!-- job listing section start -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="job-listing-section content-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                    <div class="sidebar-right">
                        <!-- Advanced search start -->
                        <div class="widget-4 advanced-search">
                            <form class="informeson">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Keywords</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Search Keywords">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchLocation" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Location">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content5">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Date Posted
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox15" type="checkbox" name="last24">
                                        <label for="checkbox15">
                                            Last 24 Hours
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox16" type="checkbox" name="last3Days">
                                        <label for="checkbox16">
                                            Last 3 days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox17" type="checkbox" name="last7Days">
                                        <label for="checkbox17">
                                            Last 7 days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="job-box">
                            <div class="company-logo">
                                <img src="~/JobImageUploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqueJobImageName)" alt="logo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <div class="float-left">
                                    <h5 class="title"><a href="@Url.Action("DetailsFromApis", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="hyberLink">@{HtmlString msg = new HtmlString(item.JobTitle); } @msg</a></h5>
                                    <div class="candidate-listing-footer">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-work"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-time"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-pin"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.locationName)</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h6>@item.PostedDate</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>

                                        @{HtmlString msg2 = new HtmlString(item.JobDescription); }@msg2
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="div-right">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Job Details", "DetailsFromApis", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "apply-button" })
                                    @{if (item.jobUrl == "")
                                        {
                                            <a href="#" class="apply-button">ApplyNow</a>
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @if (item.JobImage.Contains("x"))
                                    {

                                        <button onclick="location.href='@item.jobUrl'" type="button" class=" apply-button">View Job On Reed!</button>
                                    }
                                    else if (item.JobImage.Contains("cvx))
                                    {
                                        var c = "https://www.x.com" + @item.jobUrl;

                                        <a href="@c" class="apply-button">View x On xx!!</a>

                                    }
                                    else if (item.JobImage.Contains("xxx"))
                                    {
                                        <button onclick="location.href='@item.jobUrl'" type="button" class=" apply-button">View xxx On xxx!</button>

                                    }
                                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                    {
                                        using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApplyForYou", "Home", new { jobId = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions()
                                        {
                                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                                            UpdateTargetId = "divApply",
                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                                        }))
                                        {
                                            <button class="apply-button">We Apply For You</button>
                                        }

                                        <div class="divApply">

                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                            We apply for yous!
                                        </button>

                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">You need to register First!</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        Register with us for free!
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                                        @Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "Create", "Candidate", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
<div class="pagining text-center">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SearchResult", new
{ page, searchTitle = Request.QueryString["searchTitle"], searchLocation = Request.QueryString["searchLocation"], last24 = Request.QueryString["last24"], last3Days = Request.QueryString["last3Days"], last7Days = Request.QueryString["last7Days"] }))
</div>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

what I would like to achieve is that when a button is clicked the button get changed if meets a certain condition from the method in the controller.

In the controller I did the following:

```
  return PartialView("Applied");
```

In the PartialView I did the following:

```
<div class="apply-button" id="divApply">You have applied </div>
```

But what happens is that I get redirected to the Partial View rather than updating just the button if in case it meets the condition otherwise the button should stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the nuget package; unobstrusive ajax.

1. Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage Packages for Solution
2. Search `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobstrusive.Ajax`
3. Check solution, click Install
4. After installation, you will have a new script in your scripts folder `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`
5. Add it to your view or layout;

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

If you're using a layout, insert RenderSection after inserting the jquery script.

```
<script /> <--jquery should be here-->
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then in your view add this;

```
@section scripts {
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

---

You can also use from cdn if you don't want to install the package

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.6/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

---

Try moving your @html.beginform to inside the div instead of spanning the whole html.

```
    <div class="job-listing-section content-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                   @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
                    <div class="sidebar-right">
                        <!-- Advanced search start -->
                        <div class="widget-4 advanced-search">
                            <form class="informeson">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Keywords</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Search Keywords">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchLocation" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Location">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content5">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Date Posted
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox15" type="checkbox" name="last24">
                                        <label for="checkbox15">
                                            Last 24 Hours
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox16" type="checkbox" name="last3Days">
                                        <label for="checkbox16">
                                            Last 3 days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox17" type="checkbox" name="last7Days">
                                        <label for="checkbox17">
                                            Last 7 days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
                            </form>
                          }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: yes I just did that but I still get redirected to the partial View

Comment: thanks for letting me know about the installation of the library but I am not sure why I still get redirected to the partial view rather than just updating the content @Jerdine Sabio

Comment: @Moe will you try rebuilding the solution? or exit vs > open solution > rebuild > run

Comment: @Moe will you include the updated layout? Can you check if unobtrusive.ajax.min.js exists in your script folder?

Comment: @Moe where did you attach the script? Is it after the jquery script? Will you include the view/layout in your question

Comment: I have tried both at the beginning of the page and at the end but I will try the cdn if its not working than I will attach the whole view

Comment: @Moe when you load the page, can you check if there are errors in the console? Right click > inspect element

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @Moe add the script to your layout it has to be after jquery script

Comment: okay part of the issue is solved but still I get redirected to another page rather than updating some of the page

Comment: @Moe will you update the view in the question, I need to see the updated file, thanks

Comment: try to add type="submit" to this one `<button class="apply-button" type="submit">We Apply For You</button>`

Comment: I have updated the view I have inserted the whole code for the view

Comment: @Moe you should put the scripts inside a `@section scripts { <script /> }` see my updated answer for where to put the script

Comment: Everything works fine but the only problem that  return PartialView("Applied"); directs to completely new page rather than just updating some of the page

Comment: @Moe did you transfer the script to a render section?

Comment: @Moe I updated the answer, try moving the html.begin form.